# Platform exception while using google cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am making an app in **flutter** and using cloud function in **firebase** to update a number in Firestone,

**index.js**

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getRandomNumbers=functions.https.onCall((context)=>
{

   const numbers=admin.firestore().collection('RandomNumbers').document('CurrentRandomNumber');
   return numbers.add({
   RandomNumber=5;
   });

});
```

and this is the function

```
 onPressed: () async{
                final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
                  functionName: 'getRandomNumbers',
                );
                await callable.call().catchError((error){
                  print('$error');
                });
              },
```

The error that is coming is
**PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: NOT_FOUND, details: null, message: NOT_FOUND})**

I also found these in my log which I may think is the reason of this

```
W/DynamiteModule(12544): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(12544): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(12544): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

**NOTE**

1. I have updated my Google Play services to the latest.
2. I have taken permission of the **INTERNET** in the manifest file.
3. redownloaded the .json file and checked

Answer (score 0):

The code in your Callable Cloud Function is not correct.

By doing

```
const numbers = admin.firestore().collection('RandomNumbers').document('CurrentRandomNumber');
```

you are declaring a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html). A DocumentReference does not have an `add()` method.

If you want to get the value of a specific field of this document you should use the asynchronous [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#get) method, as follows:

```
exports.getRandomNumbers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const numbers = admin.firestore().collection('RandomNumbers').document('CurrentRandomNumber');

    return numbers.get().then(documentSnapshot => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
            console.log('Document retrieved successfully.');
            const aNumber = documentSnapshot.data().aNumber;
            // Do something
            // ...

            return null;   // or return the promise returned by an asynchronous method call,
            // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?authuser=1
        } else {
            console.log('Document does not exist.');
            return null;
        }
    })

});
```

---

If you want to increment the value of a specific field of the Firestore doc, you should probably use a [`Transaction`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html) (it depends on your exact use case).

Comment: I've added a `catch` in the code in my answer. Please try and share the error you get in the Cloud Functions log.

Comment: It is the same platform exception

Comment: As given in question

Comment: Do you confirm that this the error of the Cloud Function (from the Firebase console), **not an error from the app** (the front end)

Comment: Yes completely this happened after adding cloud function, other features like firebase auth and firestore are working perfectly fine.

Comment: My region is "asia-south1" and later on I changed my code still same error

Comment: Have you got any answer

Comment: No, sorry. I think I cannot help you anymore.

Comment: Do you have any sample app like in github